# VBA connect using named connection points

Tags: vba, visio

I have a few shapes with named connection points. Is there any way to connect them using their name?

I don't want to connect them using x,y co-ordinates.

**Example:**

Say I have two shapes S1, S2.

Connection points on S1: C11, C12
Connection points on S2: C21, C22

Now can I specify Connect S1(C11) -> S2(C21)

Comment: No, you'd basically have to write higher level code to do that using the x,y co-ordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Say you have two shapes on a Visio page object (`vzpVisioPage`), the starting shape and the ending shape:

```
Set vsoStartShape = vzpVisioPage.Shapes.Item(varSomeIndex)
Set vsoEndShape = vzpVisioPage.Shapes.Item(varSomeOtherIndex)
```

The custom connection points will be in the `Connections` section of the shapesheet.

Create a connector shape and glue it as follows:

```
Set vsoConnectorShape = vzpVisioPage.Drop(vzpVisioPage.Application.ConnectorToolDataObject, 0, 0)
vsoConnectorShape.CellsU("BeginX").GlueTo vsoStartShape.Cells("Connections.C11")
vsoConnectorShape.CellsU("EndX").GlueTo vsoEndShape.Cells("Connections.C21")
```